# Prevent Xterm Built-in Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, buffer, shortcut, key-bindings, xtermjs

Can I prevent XTERM.JS from handling shortcuts such as Ctrl+Shift+- / Ctrl+7? (Erase line)

I have searched through the project for the combination handling with no success..